# Issue of inserting data into database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute and its success without any error but the value does not insert into dbo.Quarter_SourceData. Therefore, I would like to know is there possible to merge with multiple stored proc?

I have done some research on merge with multiple stored proc but however the code for merging seems I don't understand well.

```
USE [CBC_Quarter_Report]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spDownloadQuarterSourceData]    Script Date: 12/24/2014 09:06:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDownloadQuarterSourceData]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sSQL nVarchar(Max) 
    DECLARE @sExe nVarchar(Max)
    DECLARE @QStartDate nvarchar(8)
    DECLARE @QEndDate nvarchar(8)

    SET @QStartDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR,(DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, getdate() - 8), 0)),112)
    SET @QEndDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR,(DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, getdate() - 8) + 1, 0))), 112)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Insert Client Info
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SET @sSQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT AGNT.AGNTBR, AGNT.AGNTNUM, (CLNT.SURNAME + CLNT.GIVNAME) AS AGENT_NAME,
                IPI.Policy_No, IPI.Name AS Insured_Name,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(IPI.Issue_Date AS DATE), 103) AS Date_CN_Issues,
                IPI.Inception_Date AS Contract_Commencement_Date, IPI.Expiry_Date,
                CASE WHEN PI.Transaction_Date IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(PI.Transaction_Date AS DATE), 103) END AS Date_Received,
                DATEDIFF(DAY, IPI.Issue_Date, PI.Transaction_Date) AS Days_Compliant, DT_INSERT= getdate(),
                STATUS = NULL, ACTUAL_DAY = 0
                FROM dbo.Quarter_Insured_Policy AS IPI 
                LEFT JOIN dbo.AGNTPF AGNT ON IPI.Agent_No = AGNT.AGNTNUM
                LEFT JOIN dbo.CLNTPF CLNT ON AGNT.CLNTNUM = CLNT.CLNTNUM
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Quarter_Payment AS PI ON IPI.Policy_No = PI.Policy_No
                WHERE (PI.Transaction_Date >= ' + @QStartDate + ' AND PI.Transaction_Date <= ' + @QEndDate + ')
                AND substring(AGNT.AGNTNUM, 3,1) = ''V''
                ORDER BY  AGNT.AGNTBR, AGNT.AGNTNUM'

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Quarter_SourceData

    set @sExe = 'Insert into dbo.Quarter_SourceData ' + @sSQL

    exec (@sExe)
    --print @sExe

END
```

Comment: Does the select query return any results?

Comment: use EXEC sp_executesql(@sExe)  instead of exec (@sExe). and also try execute select query in sql, and see if it returns rows or not

Comment: Hi Piyush , Its not working due its encounter an error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spDownloadQuarterSourceData, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near '@sExe'.

Comment: Hi Shree, Its return 0 results. im not sure what problem

Comment: so first correct your SELECT statement

Comment: Please do not include tags in the title of your question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your main issue. Modify your SET to add quotation marks around your dates as they are strings, just like what you did with your substring comparison.

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT AGNT.AGNTBR, AGNT.AGNTNUM, (CLNT.SURNAME + CLNT.GIVNAME) AS AGENT_NAME,
            IPI.Policy_No, IPI.Name AS Insured_Name,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(IPI.Issue_Date AS DATE), 103) AS Date_CN_Issues,
            IPI.Inception_Date AS Contract_Commencement_Date, IPI.Expiry_Date,
            CASE WHEN PI.Transaction_Date IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(PI.Transaction_Date AS DATE), 103) END AS Date_Received,
            DATEDIFF(DAY, IPI.Issue_Date, PI.Transaction_Date) AS Days_Compliant, DT_INSERT= getdate(),
            STATUS = NULL, ACTUAL_DAY = 0
            FROM dbo.Quarter_Insured_Policy AS IPI 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.AGNTPF AGNT ON IPI.Agent_No = AGNT.AGNTNUM
            LEFT JOIN dbo.CLNTPF CLNT ON AGNT.CLNTNUM = CLNT.CLNTNUM
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Quarter_Payment AS PI ON IPI.Policy_No = PI.Policy_No
            WHERE (PI.Transaction_Date >= ''' + @QStartDate + ''' AND PI.Transaction_Date <= ''' + @QEndDate + ''')
            AND substring(AGNT.AGNTNUM, 3,1) = ''V''
            ORDER BY  AGNT.AGNTBR, AGNT.AGNTNUM'
```

Also, it's best to use `EXEC sp_executesql (@sExe)` instead of `EXEC (@sExe)`.